# How to show $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{x^4+2^n}$ is continuous on $\Bbb R?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> show $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{x^4+2^n}$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$

$|\frac {1}{x^4+2^n}|\leq|\frac1{2^n}|$ Can we take $\frac1{2^n}=M$ to use M test to confirm it is uniformly convergent?

since $\sum^\infty |\frac1{2^n}|=1$ also convergent

Comment: Yes, you can. And, of course, a uniform limit of  continuous functions is ... ("*on* $\Bbb R$", not "at $\Bbb R$".)

Comment: @DavidMitra fixed thanks.When we choose M to use weierstrass M test, does it have to depend n?

Comment: Yes, it must depend on $n$ (unless you can choose $0$), since the criterion is $\sum M_n < \infty$.

Comment: You choose $M_n $ so that $|f_n(x)|\le M_n$ and $M=\sum M_n<\infty$. Here, $M_n=1/2^n$, as you suggest, works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The functions
  $$x\mapsto \frac{1}{x^4+2^n}$$
  are continuous on $\Bbb R$ for every $n\ge1$.
- We have for all $x\in\Bbb R$
  $$\frac{1}{x^4+2^n}\sim_\infty 2^{-n}$$
  and the geometric series $\sum\limits_n 2^{-n}$ is convergent so the given series is point-wise convergent on $\Bbb R$
- We have for all $x\in\Bbb R$
  $$\left|\frac{1}{x^4+2^n}\right|\le 2^{-n}$$
  so we have the uniform convergence of the series on $\Bbb R$.
  These points allow us to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your curiosity, there is a closed form of this summation $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{x^4+2^n}=\frac{\psi _{\frac{1}{2}}^{(0)}\left(-\frac{\log \left(-\frac{x^4}{2}\right)}{\log
   (2)}\right)-\log (2)}{x^4 \log (2)}$$ where appears the  q-digamma function.